# How to select conditional rows and only return one result with groupby? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to get the only row after groupby with the certain rules(

- get the tier with rank = 1 if tier != Unknown.           (a001)
- Or get the tier with rank =2                             (b001)
- return tier = 'no_tier' if rank = 1 and tier = Unknown   (c001)

** "Unknown" would only show up once for the tier of each user_id

Here is the dataframe

```
user_id tier    rank
a001    High     1
a001    Low      2
a001    Unknown  3
b001    Unknown  1 
b001    Mid      2
c001    Unknown  1
```

expected result

```
tier    
High     
Mid      
no_tier
```

I was trying to write down a function like

```
def get_tier(x):
    if x['rank'] ==1 and x['tier'] != 'Unknown':
        return x['tier']
    elif x['rank'] == 2:
        return x['tier']
    else:
        return 'no_tier'

df.goupby('user_id').apply(lambda x : x.apply(get_tier), axis = 1).iloc[0]).reset_index()


but seems like it cant work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your conditions and assuming that the ranks are already sorted in ascending order (per group or globally), you can just replace unknown with NA, get the first non-NA value with [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html), then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with :

```
out = (df
       #.sort_values(by='rank')  # uncomment if not originally sorted
       ['tier']
       .replace('Unknown', pd.NA)
       .groupby(df['user_id']).first()
       .fillna('no_tier')
      )
```

Output:

```
user_id
a001       High
b001        Mid
c001    no_tier
Name: tier, dtype: object
```

If you rather want the original rows, you can go with a [`groupby.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) to the the min rank per group after masking the Unknown ranks with large number (e.g. Inf):

```
out = (df.loc[df['rank'].mask(df['tier'].eq('Unknown'), float('inf'))
             .groupby(df['user_id']).idxmin()]
         .replace({'tier': {'Unknown': 'no_tier'}})
      )
```

Output:

```
  user_id     tier  rank
0    a001     High     1
4    b001      Mid     2
5    c001  no_tier     1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

1. remain only 2 rows of `df` by `user_id` (variable `tmp`)
2. mask Unknown of `tmp['tier']`
3. groupby + first + fillna (by 'no_tier')

```
tmp = df.groupby('user_id').head(2)
out = tmp['tier'].mask(tmp['tier'].eq('Unknown'))\
                 .groupby(tmp['user_id']).first().fillna('no_tier')
```

out:

```
user_id
a001       High
b001        Mid
c001    no_tier
Name: tier, dtype: object
```

---

If your dataset is not sorted by `rank column`, use the following code to create `tmp` instead of the above code:

```
tmp = df[df['rank'].isin([1, 2])].sort_values('rank')
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'user_id': ['a001', 'a001', 'a001', 'b001', 'b001', 'c001'], 
         'tier': ['High', 'Low', 'Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Mid', 'Unknown'],
         'rank': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'user_id': ['a001', 'a001', 'a001', 'b001', 'b001', 'c001'],
    'tier': ['High', 'Low', 'Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Mid', 'Unknown'],
    'rank': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def get_tier(group):
    # Applying the rules in order
    if (group['rank'] == 1).any() and (group[group['rank'] == 1]['tier'].iloc[0] != 'Unknown'):
        return group[group['rank'] == 1]['tier'].iloc[0]
    elif (group['rank'] == 2).any():
        return group[group['rank'] == 2]['tier'].iloc[0]
    else:
        return 'no_tier'

result = df.sort_values(by=['rank']).groupby('user_id').apply(get_tier).reset_index(name='tier')
print(result)
```

My output:

```
user_id     tier
0    a001     High
1    b001      Mid
2    c001  no_tier
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work for you,

```
    import pandas as pd

# DF using your data
data = {
    'user_id': ['a001', 'a001', 'a001', 'b001', 'b001', 'c001'],
    'tier': ['High', 'Low', 'Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Mid', 'Unknown'],
    'rank': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a function to determine the tier based on conditions
def determine_tier(group):
    if 'High' in group.values:
        return 'High'
    elif 'Mid' in group.values:
        return 'Mid'
    else:
        return 'no_tier'

# Group by 'user_id' and apply the determine_tier function
result_df = df.groupby('user_id')['tier'].agg(determine_tier).reset_index()

# Rename the columns as needed
result_df.columns = ['user_id', 'tier']

# Display the result
print(result_df)
```

[image: output]